# Do I need to open same kernel config on host machine, if I want to run app on virtual machine?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, virtual-machine

Some examples:

1. I want to use huge page on virtual machine, do I need to open huge page support on physical machine? I checked this article, which said for 2MB huge page, it's not needed. But for 1GiB ones, physical machine should also open huge page. May I know the reason for it? [text](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/04/27/benchmarking-transparent-versus-1gib-static-huge-page-performance-in-linux-virtual-machines#)
2. When running eBPF on virtual machine, I need to set kernel config like CONFIG_BPF=y CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y, etc. Do I need to set same kernel config on physical machine?

My guess is no because virtual and physical machine seems to be independent operating system, is that the case? Thank you.

Comment: You can't have huge pages on the VM without huge pages on the host. Huge pages are a physical resource.